# Sliding a view in with a touch gesture

Tags: android

I am trying to replicate the behaviour of the the Camera application on Android where camera and videos can be swiped in by the user but the user controls the position of the views with their swipe. E.g. if I swipe and stop halfway, the views will be half animated.

[image: Android camera application]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The end result was a solution using a viewpager with an adapter that has pages between layouts.

The end pager view looked something similar to:

View (Empty) -> View (Camera Controls)

The view pager is assigned to page one (Camera Controls) and the user can swipe left to get rid of the controls. I used the position given by the Page Transformer to give each element a different 'velocity'.